# 実際に出力されているサンプリングレート

Tags: android

AndroidでOpenSLESを利用してPCM出力をしているのですが、今スピーカーやイヤホンから実際に出力されている音声のサンプルレートを取得する方法をご存知でしたら教えていただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: おそらく何かやりたいことがあってこの質問の形になっているのだと思うのですが、自前で出力した音声が、そこから出力機器までのどこかで劣化していないか知りたいということでしょうか？　再生されている音声ファイル側で定められているサンプルレートではなく、実際に再生しているデバイスがどの程度細かく再生しているか知りたい、というお話だと解釈したのですが……。

Comment: レスポンスありがとうございます。nekketsuuu様のご認識の通りです。例えば96kHzのPCMデータを96kHzで出力するようにOpenSLESに設定しても、端末が対応していなければ実際は48.0kHzや44.1kHzで出力しているようなことはあると思います。このときの48.0kHz(or 44.1kHz)という情報を取得したいと考えています。AudioTrack#getNativeOutputSampleRateでそれっぽい値が取れそうだなとは思っているのですが、これが正しいのかいまいち自信が無く。